# Invoking a default method inside a static method of interface

Tags: java, java-8

I need to call a default method inside the interface's static method (two methods in the same interface- one is default and other one is static). Is this possible? If so, how can I achieve this?

Look at the code portion to better understand my question:

```
interface A{
default void callee(){
        //do something here
    }

    static void caller(){
        //call callee() method anyhow
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your code and say what's concrete problem that you have.

Comment: Why does your static method need to be static when it needs to call an instance method. If behavior depends on state, it should probably not be static.

Comment: I only can think of `static void caller( A a ) { a.callee(); }` but I doubt it's what you are looking for. And personally I'd make it an instance method in that case most probably. Being of void return-type I assume it changes state of some instance. So you need an instance anyway. I somehow think this could be an x-y-Problem. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need instance to call non-static method.

```
static void caller() {
    new A(){}.callee();
}
```

It is better to avoid static to non-static calls. I suppose you can extract part of `callee` to static method.

Answer (score 2):

Default methods are methods that will get inherited 'default' by all the classes implementing the interface. This avoids having to rewrite a the method for every class implementing the interface.
You can only call the default method from callee 'A' using an object instance of a class implementing the 'A' interface.

You have 2 options:

1. pass an A-object as a parameter to the static 'caller' method.

   ```
   interface A {
       default void callee(){
           //do something here
       }

       static void caller(A anAInstance){
           anAInstance.callee();
       }
   }
   ```
2. make an anonymous class inside this method.

   ```
   interface A {
       default void callee(){
           //do something here
       }

       static void caller(){
           new A(){}.callee();
       }
   }
   ```

For more information on default methods see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html